# Using Linq for copying/filtering produces a dynamic result in foreach loops?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

So I create this projection of a dictionary of items I would like to remove.

```
var toRemoveList =
    this.outputDic.Keys.Where(key =>
        this.removeDic.ContainsKey(key));
```

Then I iterate through the result removing from the actual dictionary

```
        foreach(var key in toRemoveList)
            this.outputDic.Remove(key);
```

However during that foreach an exception is thrown saying that the list was modified during the loop. But, how so? is the linq query somewhat dynamic and gets re evaluated every time the dictionary changes? A simple .ToArray() call on the end of the query solves the issues, but imo, it shouldn't even occur in the first place.

Comment: `foreach(var key in toRemoveList.toList())` What if you're adding things to the list in the loop? That could be an infinite loop right there.

Comment: ^ What he said.  The difference is that `Linq` queries are lazily executed (get the next one, stop working, check if there's another? Get the next one, stop working....check if there's another?) During the "stop working" step it defers to the content of the for loop (in this case).

Comment: I see, so in this case, the query is executed at each step of the foreach call?

Comment: Well...no: the expressions you use to generate your linq query are executed at every step of the way...Have you ever seen the 'yield' operator?

Comment: You might find it interesting to know what low level details causes the exception itself.  Your foreach loop calls `toRemoveList.MoveNext`, which calls `outputDicEnumerator.MoveNext()`.  `outputDicEnumerator` is a initialized with the code `outputDicEnumerator.version = outputDic.version;`.  Calling `outputDic.Remove` calls `outputDic.version++;`.  Calling `outputDicEnumerator.MoveNext()` runs `if (outputDicEnumerator.version != outputDic.version) throw ...;`.

Comment: I see, thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 14):

> So I create this projection of a dictionary of items I would like to remove.

```
var toRemoveList =
  this.outputDic.Keys.Where(key =>
    this.removeDic.ContainsKey(key));
```

As I have often said, if I can teach people one thing about LINQ it is this:  **the result of a query expression is a query, not the results of executing the query**.  You now have an object that means "the keys of a dictionary such that the key is... something". It is not the *results* of that query, it is *that query*. The query is an object unto itself; it does not give you a result set until you ask for one.

Then you do this:

```
    foreach(var key in toRemoveList)
        this.outputDic.Remove(key);
```

So what are you doing?  You are iterating over the query. Iterating over the query executes the query, so the *query* is iterating over the *original dictionary*.  But you then remove an item from the dictionary, *while you are iterating over it*, which is illegal.

> imo, it shouldn't even occur in the first place.

Your opinion about how the world should be is a common one, but doing it your way leads to deep inefficiencies. Let us suppose that *creating a query executes the query immediately* rather than *creates a query object*.  What does this do?

```
var query = expensiveRemoteDatabase
    .Where(somefilter)
    .Where(someotherfilter)
    .OrderBy(something);
```

The first call to `Where` produces a query, which in your world is then *executed*, pulling down from the remote database all records which match that query.  The second call to `Where` then says "oh, sorry, I meant to also apply this filter here as well, can we do that whole query again, this time with the second filter?" and so then *that* whole record set is computed, and then we say "oh, no, wait, I forgot to tell you when you built that last query object, we're going to need to sort it, so database, can you run this query for me a third time?"

Now perhaps do you see why queries produce *a query* that then does not execute until it needs to?

Comment: "oh, sorry, I meant to also apply this filter here as well!" Good one.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `toRemoveList` does not contain a list of things to be removed, it contains a description of how to get a list of things that can be removed.

If you **step through this in a debugger** using F11 you can see this quite clearly for yourself. The first point it stops is with the cursor on `foreach` which is what you would expect.

Next you stop at `toRemoveList` (the one in `foreach(var key in toRemoveList)`). This is where it is setting up the iterator.

When you step through `var key` (with F11) however it now jumps into the original definition of `toRemoveList`, specifically the `this.removeDic.ContainsKey(key)` part. Now you get an idea of what is really happening.

The `foreach` is calling the iterators `Next` method to move to the next point in the dictionary's keys and holds onto the list. When you call into `this.outputDic.Remove(key);` this detects that the iterator hasn't finished and therefore stops you with this error.

As everybody is saying on here, the correct way to solve this is to use `ToArray()`/`ToList()` as what these do is to give you another copy of the list. So the you have one to step through, and one to remove from.

Answer (score 2):

The `.ToArray()` solves the issues because it forces you to evaluate the entire enumeration and cache the local values. Without doing so, when you enumerate through it the enumerable attempts to calculate the first index, return that, then return to the collection and calculate the next index. If the underlying collection you're iterating over changes, you can no longer guarantee that the enumeration will return the appropriate value.

In short: just force the evaluation with `.ToArray()` (or `.ToList()`, or whatever).

Comment: The OP doesn't want `ToArray()`

Comment: @KingKing are you the idiot who's downvoting all the answers and clearly doesn't understand how LINQ works? I don't care what the OP wants, the OP NEEDS `ToArray()` or `ToList()`, there is no other way to write the code.

Comment: I don't mind the ToArray, I just wanted to know why it is needed

Comment: @evanmcdonnal PLEASE read the OP's question carefully: He said `ToArray() call on the end of the query solves the issues, but imo, it shouldn't even occur in the first place`

Comment: @LukasTaves see my anser above, i have mentioned the reason fully.

Comment: @KingKing: I thought I did a pretty good job explaining why it doesn't really matter what OP wants. It's not possible and I've explained why.

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ query uses deferred execution. It streams the items one by one, retruning them as they're requested. So yes, every time you try to remove a key it changes the result which is why it throws an exception. When you invoke `ToArray()` it forces execution of the query which is why it works.

EDIT: This is somewhat in response to your comments. Check out [iterator blocks on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee5kxzk0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) this is the mechanism being used when your for each executes. Your query just gets turned into an expression tree and the filter, projects, operation ect is applied to the elements one by one when they're retrieved unless it is not possible.

Comment: The OP doesn't want `ToArray()`

Comment: It's not the only option.  `var toRemoveList = removeDic.Keys.Where(key => outputDic.ContainsKey(key))` works just fine because the foreach loop then enumerates over `removeDic` instead of `outputDic`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this error is because of deferred execution of linq. To explain it fully when  your loop runs is actually when the data is fetch from the dictionary. **Thus modification in outputdic takes place at this point of time and it is not allowed to modify the collection you are looping upon**. This is why you get this error. You can get rid of this error by asking the compiler to execute it before you run the loop.

```
var toRemoveList =
this.outputDic.Keys.Where(key =>
    this.removeDic.ContainsKey(key)).ToList();
```

Notice the ToList() in the above statement. It will make sure that your query has been executed and you have your list in toRemoveList.

Comment: The OP doesn't want something not `deferred`

Comment: @KingKing he is getting the error and he doesn't knows why it is happening. I have explained that. What is wrong with that? And i have explained in my answer why modification is taking place at this point

Comment: @evanmcdonnal well before passing our comments we should take his point of view.